# parse json using java (simplejson)

Tags: java, json, parsing, yql

I need to parse json which I get from YQL but I am having trouble as I am not getting the results I need. I am using simple json [(https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples)](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples) and trying to follow the documentation. The problem is the example they show are very limited (I am very new to json). I want to extract everything in the array (Sy, Date, O, H, L, C, and V ). In the documentation they show how to extarct elements from an array if the json object is just as an array, but  I have an array + some extra stuff on top:

```
{"query"
        {"count":200,"created":"2014-06-17T00:46:43Z","lang":"en-GB","results"
```

This is the full json object, how would I extract just the array?

```
{"query"
    {"count":200,"created":"2014-06-17T00:46:43Z","lang":"en-GB","results"
        {"array":[{"Sy":"Y","Date":"2010-03-10","O":"16.51","H":"16.94","L":"16.51","C":"16.79","V":"33088600"},
                  {"Sy":"Y","Date":"2010-03-09","O":"16.41","H":"16.72","L":"16.40","C":"16.53","V":"20755200"},
                  {"Sy":"Y","Date":"2010-03-08","O":"16.32","H":"16.61","L":"16.30","C":"16.52","V":"30554000"}
        ]}}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i use https://code.google.com/p/org-json-java/downloads/list

this is simple

```
try{
        String json = "JSON source";
        JSONObject j = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray arr = j.getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("results").getJSONArray("array");
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length(); i++){
            JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
            String sy = obj.getString("Sy");
            String date = obj.getString("Date");
            String o = obj.getString("O");
            String h = obj.getString("H");
            String l = obj.getString("L");
            String c = obj.getString("C");
            String v = obj.getString("V");
        }
    }
    catch(JSONException e){

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to extract the array you need piece by piece.

```
JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();
String s="{YOUR_JSON_STRING}";
JSONArray array=parser.parse(s).get("query") //"query"
                .get("result") // "query->result"
                .get("array"); // THE array you need
```

Note that you might need to use `try...catch...` block to deal with exceptions.

Since you are using java, I highly recommend gson, which is written by google. It can convert json to object directly, which means you don't need to get the array deep inside the json step by step. https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Generally speaking, you can use gson to parse json piece by piece with jsonparser or, convert the whole json to a object with gson.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will have a look at it!